# Rails Activerecord Model with 2 foreign keys, neither accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

Hey everybody I have a scenario here I am really trying to figure out.  I am trying to build a custom blog in Rails which requires users to be signed in to leave a comment.  Basically I have 3 models - Post, User, and Comment.  My problem is mainly with the comment model.
  I am trying to have it so that a Comment belongs_to a User and also belongs_to Post, which have many comments.  I also have made the post_id and the user_id inaccessible as I do not want them to be tampered with (I want the comment to be automatically associated with the id of the post on which it was left, and I want the user to be automatically determined via session).  My problem is that I am not really sure how I can create a valid comment.  If I try to add a comment doing @blog.comments.build(@attr) I am ignoring the inacessible User, and of course if I try to build it through the User I am ignoring the blog.

My guess is there is a much better way to do this and I might just be approaching it wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have this in the Comment model:

```
attr_accessible :content
```

and when you try to build a comment this happens:

```
@post = Post.first
@post.comments.build(:user=>current_user)
# => WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
```

So that won't work.

If you want to protect the user_id and post_id from being overwritten on an update, you could do this:

```
attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :post_id
attr_readonly :user_id, :post_id

@post = Post.first
@post.comments.build(:user=>current_user)
@post.save! 
# sets user_id when creating
@post.user_id = 37
@post.save! 
# saves, but user_id is not changed. No warning is logged.
@post.update_attributes(:user_id=>37)
# same as above
@post.update_attribute(:user_id,37)
# raises ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: user_id is marked as readonly
```

But this seems like overkill, since presumably your application would not submit a form with a user_id for an existing comment, and someone would have to code up their own form and post it to change the ID.

Comment: so are you saying that making the user_id accessible is still secure?  i was just worried about the possible manipulation of a form on posting, but now that i think on it i can use session to simply verify that the person posting the form is actually the right user, correct?

Comment: Right, if you use the session then there is no issue of someone passing in arbitrary data in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just set the relation manually:

```
comment = @post.build(@attr)
comment.user = @user
comment.save
```

At least, I'm pretty sure that would work.

Comment: I tried this but got an undefined method exception.  I expected this too as in the model I only have 'attr_accessible :content' and not user_id or anything of the like.  Since the user will have to be logged in to leave a comment I was hoping to include a session helper and in the comment model simply have a beforesave method do something like 'self.user_id = current_user' or something similar.  Any thoughts?

Comment: as a side note if I include user_id in the attr_accessible part of the model your method works.  but like I said I would ideally just like to set the user_id via session as opposed to passing in a user variable via post, as imo this seems less likely to be tampered with

Comment: Why not get the @user from the session, and then assign it? Then your code is clear what is happening. If you put it in the before_save, you might have a situation down the road where lets say an Admin is editing the item, then will the Admin's user get saved to it because that is the current session?

Comment: this is more or less what i am thinking now.  see my comment on zetetic's answer.  i was just worried that introducing the user_id as an accessible attribute would introduce other issues, but if i use session to verify the user posting the form then i should be in the clear, right?

Comment: Yes, the comparison of the user submitted user_id to the session user_id should ensure only correct users can update records.